# Composer ignoring auth.json

Tags: authentication, composer-php

Even though i have auth.json in my $COMPOSER_HOME and it's loaded, composer still requires me to type credentials on install/update.

This is the output of `composer update -vvv` that confirms that auth.json has been loaded

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file /home/user/.config/composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/user/.config/composer/auth.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/var/www/html/api): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/user/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/html/api/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer
Running 1.6.3 (2018-01-31 16:28:17) with PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 on Linux / 4.15.0-38-generic
Loading composer repositories with package information
Executing command (/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/https---private.server.io-private-repo.git/): git rev-parse --git-dir
Executing command (/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/https---private.server.io-private-repo.git/): git remote -v
Executing command (/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/https---private.server.io-private-repo.git/): git remote set-url origin 'https://private.server.io/private/repo.git' && git remote update --prune origin
Username for 'https://private.server.io':
```

This is my auth.json in /home/user/.config/composer/auth.json:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "private.server.io": {
            "username": "myUsername",
            "password": "myPassword"
        }
    }
}
```

I copied settings from my old computer where it worked but now it doesn't.  I've deleted the auth.json and composer asked me if I want it to remember my credentials, which I said yes, but nothing worked. Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 4):

This is known behavior in Ubuntu18.04 if you use the same. But if you just hit `enter` each time it asks for username and password, it will pick them from auth.json and will complete the composer install/update.

Answer (score 1):

yes, pressing `enter` works. For scripts you can set the environment variable `GIT_ASKPASS=echo`